# Remove excess whitespace in R pie charts?

Tags: r, pie-chart, margins

Is there any way to reduce the amount of whitespace around pie charts generated using the base plotting tools in R?

I'd like to create a multi-panel figure but I can't figure out a way to reduce the amount of whitespace around the plot.

Example code:

```
par(mfrow=c(2,1))
pie(1:5)
pie(rep(1,5))
```

I tried playing with `mar`, `omi`, and `oma` within `par()`, but all values for those vectors seem to already be set to zero, and negative values are not accepted.  Any way around this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Graphical Parameters about the margin size of plots:

- `mai`: the margin size in inches
- `mar`: the margin size in lines of text
- `omi`: the size of the outer margins in inches
- `oma`: the size of the outer margins in lines of text

All above are specified with a numerical vector of the form `c(bottom, left, top, right)`.

---

The default value of `mai` is :

```
> par("mai")
[1] 1.02 0.82 0.82 0.42
```

You can reset it as:

```
> par(mfrow = c(2, 1), mai = c(0, 0, 0, 0))
```